# Nodejs unittest Mocking protractor $ module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, protractor, sinon, mockery

A little background: I want to write a unittest for the below function. However whenever I import the function into a unittest and try to run it I receive `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. `$` is coming from the protractor library so I was looking for a way to stub it but I haven't been able to find a way to do this. I've tried using the sinon and mockery libraries so far.

My question is how can I mock `$` so I can write a unittest for this?

````
const { $ } = require('protractor');

/**
 * Function for resolving object types.
 *
 *
 * resolveType($('.save-button'));
 * ```
 *
 * @param {*} locator
 * @return {Object} returns object with the element, a selector, and
 *                  it's description for element
 */
module.exports = function verifyType(locator) {

  return {
    element: $(mySelector),
    selector: mySelector,
    description: locator.description,
  };
};
````

Update - Here is my current unittest attempt for this. It fails with `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`:

```
const resolveType = require('../../path/toResolveType').resolveType;
const mochaccino = require('mochaccino');

const { expect } = mochaccino;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { $ } = require('protractor');

const locator_a = { description: '"embed ID" text box', selector: '#embed-id' };


describe('commands.resolveType', function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
    sinon.stub($).returns('test');
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    $.restore();
  });

  it('Standard locator with CSS selector', function() {
    const answer = resolveType(locator_a);
    // Placeholder till I can get answer to evaluate.
    expect('a').toEqual('a');
  });
});
```

Comment: protractor is for end2end tests

Comment: I know. But I'm trying to write a unittest for this method that I use with protractor.

Comment: Try to import it this way `const {browser, element, $, $$, by, Key} = require("protractor");`

Comment: Will try, but having trouble putting it together. Updating with comment feedback @SergeyPleshakov.